# Relocating SVN working copy following branch rename

Tags: svn

Is there a way to alter the branch to which a working copy relates?

Another developer has renamed the branch im wokring on, so I cant commit any work any more.

Could I just edit all the .svn directory files to point to the new location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the working copy directory:

```
svn switch http://server/svn/branches/newbranch
```

Answer (score 5):

You almost answered it yourself, you can do this by relocating:

```
svn switch --relocate FROM TO
```

for example

```
svn switch --relocate http://server/svn/repos/branches/foo \
    http://server/svn/repos/branches/bar
```

Comment: I am getting this error "svn: Relocate can only change the repository part of an URL" when issuing this command. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102758/how-to-renaming-a-svn-branch-and-update-references-in-an-existing-sandbox

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct.  I believe a simple "svn switch" should do the job if only the name of the branch changed.  "svn switch --relocate" is only usefull if the IP-address, hostname, or protocol has changed.  Relocating is something that normally should happen only very infrequently.