# How to rename an SVN branch and update references in an existing sandbox?

Tags: svn, branch, rename

I needed to rename a SVN branch, so I did:

```
$ svn move https://server/repos/myrepo/branches/oldbranch \
    https://server/repos/myrepo/branches/newbranch
```

So far, so good --  the branch has been renamed.

The trouble is, we have existing sandboxes checked out from this branch and when I try to update I get this error:

```
$ svn update
svn: Target path '/branches/oldbranch' does not exist
```

A fairly self-explanatory error. After a quick search I thought I had found the solution: [Relocating SVN working copy following branch rename](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4411003/341459)

The trouble is, that when I try to issue that command I get another error:

```
$ svn switch --relocate https://server/repos/myrepo/branches/oldbranch \
    https://server/repos/myrepo/branches/newbranch
svn: Relocate can only change the repository part of an URL
```

As far as I can see, I am using the `--relocate` command the same way as Sander Rijken. Any ideas why I get this error?

Comment: I don't hink the answer from Sander Rijken is correct.  I have added a comment on his answer.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Just do

```
svn switch https://server/repos/myrepo/branches/newbranch
```

from within your working copy.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but it does delete all of the unversioned files from the sandbox when I next do an `svn update`... something I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: `From within your working copy` => you mean "`cd [oldbranch]` first then, from there, type the command `svn switch [...]`?

Comment: I realize @OlivierPons's question is 7 years old, but since nobody confirmed - for the sake of future visitors here, yes - you would do `cd oldbranch` then `svn switch ^/branches/newbranch` (note that the ^ tells svn that you're switching relative to the current branch's root path.)

Answer (score 5):

For changing relative path you **must** to use **pure** `svn switch` (and anyway `switch --relocate` is deprecated), as written in `svn help switch` for 1-st form

> `switch URL[@PEGREV] [PATH]`
> Update the working copy to mirror a new URL within the repository.
>
> ```
>  This behavior is similar to 'svn update', and is the way to
>  move a working copy to a branch or tag within the same repository.
> ```

I.e in the root of WC for `oldbranch`, which is now `newbranch`, you have to use

`svn switch ^/branches/newbranch`

Answer (score 3):

If you had simply wanted to rename a SVN branch in Eclipse, the easiest would have been to go into the *SVN Repository Exploring Perspective*, and then right click on your branch -> Refactor-> Rename