# How To Rename Branch which was created from trunk?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to "rename" a SVN branch and after "rename" has been done, the original branch-name must not exist anymore in branches, i.e. just like directory/file rename.

I have been searching and only got results like, First go for Deleting it then re-create from trunk...bla,bla,bla etc. 
which wasn't as per my requirement.

**NOTE**: I'd like to use TortoiseSVN client for this if possible.

Comment: This question already has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102758/how-to-rename-an-svn-branch-and-update-references-in-an-existing-sandbox

Comment: @intermedi_8 nothing about TortoiseSVN in referenced question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Copy the branch to a new name, then delete the old one.

In TortoiseSVN, you can:

- right-click on the folder > TortoiseSVN > Repo-browser
- find the branch you want to rename
- right click on it > Rename

Comment: Thanks but, I feel little bit fear in it. may be it's worked but does ancestor remains same ? I mean while further operation want to perform e.g. merge-to-trunk, merge-to-branch. at that time will not it effect in a negativly ?

Comment: Merge will work the same way as usualy. To SVN, this "copy and delete" looks similar to ordinary branching (it will be like branching from a tag, or branching from another branch).

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but I'm new to SVN. After renaming how to you switch to the renamed branch? I tried using `switch` but it told me that the URL is invalid (the URL I got from the repo browser by right clicking on the renamed branch and copying its URL to the clipboard). Should I use checkout or...?

Comment: @rbaleksandar if you don't have any uncommited work, checkout might be the easiest option.

Comment: Thanks. I resolved my issue with the repo browser again. It's pretty easy: drag&drop the branch to where you want to place it and then rename it (or just do the remaining with the new path). After that switch or checkout did the trick.

Comment: You might have spaces in the path which will not be copied correctly! Be sure it is exactly the same name even after copied, or simply use the file browsing to chose the directory from switch dialog